# How do i put userinput into text file using php?

Tags: php

Purpose of this code: takes userinput from HTML & put it into server-side config file

code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Create Prefix from user-input </title>
</head>
<body>
<FORM method="POST">
Enter prefix name : <input type="text" name="str"> <br/> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Create Directory">
</FORM>
<?php
$var = $_POST["str"];
$txt = "#$var
filter f_$var { match("$var" value("MESSAGE")); };
log { source ( s_net ); filter( f_$var ); destination ( df_$var ); };
destination     df_$var {
file("/var/www/html/cts/$var/${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}.log"  perm(0644));
};
#$var";
$myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
</body>
</HTML>
```

This code should add new line at the end of the log.txt fil. i expect to add $txt defined value should be  added in logs.txt file

what i did:
i created a simple form for userinput i.e prefix=hi & named that userinput box as "str"
i created that userinput variable like this
$var = $_POST["str"]
$txt = hello there $var how are you $var

then i used function :file_put_contents to put content of $txt in a logs.txt file

Its not working, Please if anyone can help me

Comment: Sorry but it's really unclear what you've written and what you want to do. I read you question a few times and still don't get what do you want to do

Comment: The syntax highlighting here should give you an indicator as to why it might be “not working” … Go and enable proper PHP error reporting first of all, if you have not done that already.

Answer (score 0):

here is a proposed running version of putUserInputToTextFile.php

```
<?php

echo '<FORM method="POST" action="./putUserInputToTextFile.php">
Enter prefix name : <input type="text" name="str"> <br/> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Write to Logs.txt">
</FORM>';

$txt = $_POST["str"];
 
$myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

above has 3 lines:
line1 echoes the form
line2 takes value of $_POST["str"] that was submitted on form
line3 writes the value to ./logs.txt

please note the file: putUserInputToTextFile.php has on a webserver (such) as:  as http://localhost/someFolder/putUserInputToTextFile.php or similar.
'hope this helps.